# ojdbc8 jar is not getting loaded in Tomcat8

Tags: java, jdbc, tomcat8, ojdbc

We are using Tomcat8, (Tomcat 8.0.30 to be exact) and Java8 for our application. with ojdbc7 database driver along with all other jars come along e.g. ucp.jar and ons.jar etc. with Oracle database 11g. if I enable 'verbose:class' on my java application i.e. in Tomcat, it shows all the classes getting loaded from ojdbc.jar and ucp.jar files.

Now we have upgraded our database to 12c, hence we are upgrading database driver to 12.2 ojdbc8.jar. I replaced all jars (ojdbc, ucp, ons), But Tomcat complaining and giving error NoClassDefFound exception.   When I used the same verbose 'verbose:class' option, I see no class getting loaded from ojdbc8.jar. (classes from ucp.jar does get loaded). And the jar files right there at location $CATALINA_HOME/lib. But not sure why ojdbc8.jar is not getting loaded.

Appreciate any help to resolve this issue.

This is the exception about NoClassFoundException

```
SEVERE: The required Server component failed to start so Tomcat is 
unable to start.
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component 
[StandardServer[43004]]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:625)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:351)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:485)
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at oracle.ucp.jdbc.PoolDataSourceImpl.allowSetter(PoolDataSourceImpl.java)
at oracle.ucp.jdbc.PoolDataSourceImpl.setUser(PoolDataSourceImpl.java:2089)
at oracle.ucp.jdbc.PoolDataSourceImpl.getObjectInstance(PoolDataSourceImpl.java:3945)
at com.intralinks.tomcat.ucp.UcpDataSourceFactory.getObjectInstance(UcpDataSourceFactory.java:68)
at org.apache.naming.factory.FactoryBase.getObjectInstance(FactoryBase.java:94)
at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getObjectInstance(NamingManager.java:321)
at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:841)
at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:152)
at org.apache.naming.NamingContextBindingsEnumeration.nextElementInternal(NamingContextBindingsEnumeration.java:117)
at org.apache.naming.NamingContextBindingsEnumeration.next(NamingContextBindingsEnumeration.java:71)
at org.apache.naming.NamingContextBindingsEnumeration.next(NamingContextBindingsEnumeration.java:34)
at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener.createMBeans(GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener.java:138)
at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener.createMBeans(GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener.java:145)
at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener.createMBeans(GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener.java:110)
at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent(GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener.java:82)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:95)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase.java:402)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setState(LifecycleBase.java:347)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:762)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
... 7 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle/jdbc/logging/annotations/Supports
at oracle.jdbc.logging.runtime.Features.<init>(Features.java:45)
at oracle.jdbc.logging.runtime.TraceControllerImpl.<clinit>(TraceControllerImpl.java:32)
... 28 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle/jdbc/logging/annotations/Supports
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
at oracle.jdbc.logging.runtime.Features.<init>(Features.java:33)
... 29 more
```

Comment: What Java version are you using? ojdbc8 is for Java 8 or higher. In any case, without a [mcve] and relevant exception stacktrace we can't really help.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel - Sure Mark, I do have Java 1.8. Java 1.8.0_144 to be exact.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would like to take this question back. It seems somewhere ojdbc7.jar is hardcoded under the tomcat. Because when I renamed the ojdbc8.jar to ojdbc7.jar then it works. So it has to be hardcoded somewhere. I havent found yet, but I will. It is not catalina.properties.